Why does MySQL return multiple rows on a unique index (when casting)?
Not sure if this is a bug, but when selecting from a table using a unique index (and implicit casting of type), multiple rows are returned, one of which is obviously wrong.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS index_test;

CREATE TABLE index_test (
    string VARCHAR(40),
    number BIGINT,
    
    UNIQUE INDEX uq_string(string),
    UNIQUE INDEX uq_number(number)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO index_test
(string, number)
VALUES
("42356411000001102", 42356411000001102),
("42356411000001104", 42356411000001104);

SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE number = 42356411000001102;      -- 1 Row        NATIVE BIGINT
SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE string = "42356411000001102";    -- 1 Row        NATIVE VARCHAR
SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE number = "42356411000001102";    -- 1 Row        CASTING
SELECT * FROM index_test WHERE string = 42356411000001102;      -- 2 ROWS!!!    CASTING


Even weirder is how logically could a word be an integer?  As in the last test, says its looking for a string but you gave it an integer .. so the fact it even worked is weirder than it got responses.    You can get away with passing an integer as a string but you can't get away with passing a string as an integer.

Duplicate of Why does mysql 'select where clause' query wrongly?

It is similar, not sure if identical.  And let's get honest, he posted the code to the question and the one you linked is a picture of code, so if that person in the link updates their post, then you might have a point.

@GuyIncognito - he had no mention of indexes so could be tablescan.  BUT it raises the interesting point that the same issue may exist reading either table data or index data.

It is for the same reason I explained.  x = 1 is x having a numerical value of 1, but x = '1' means it has no numerical value but instead is the word or a string of the number 1.   Numbers need to be numbers and strings need to be strings, but people get confused because you can pass the integer as a string to MySQL and it knows its a number because its defined as such in the datatype for that column, but if the column is a varchar you do not want to pass it x = 1 you want x = '1' so it knows to use the words not the numerical value.

Indexing has nothing to do with it. The result is the same with or without indexes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html says:

The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:
...

In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (double-precision) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.


Comparing a string to a numeric falls into the "all other cases" category. The numbers you show are cast to DOUBLE, but that doesn't have enough precision to represent such a large number without rounding off.
mysql> select cast('42356411000001102' as double) as `string`,
  cast(42356411000001104 as double) as `number`, 
  cast('42356411000001102' as double) = cast(42356411000001104 as double) as `matches`;

+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| string              | number              | matches |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 4.23564110000011e16 | 4.23564110000011e16 |       1 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+

This behavior is independent of using an index, unique or not. I get the same result if I have no index defined in the test table.

I posted this answer even though it is a duplicate, to show how the specific values in the OP's question result in rounding. But the answer is basically the same as that in the linked duplicate question. I've marked my answer as community wiki so I don't get points for it.

To properly prove this is the case, I modified your SQL slightly with the original values to show "matches" is still truthy (your SQL has the same value on both sides of the comparison)
select cast('42356411000001102' as double) = cast(42356411000001104 as double) as matches; 

Thanks, I've edited to fix that in my answer above.
